# probability question: word game

Tags: probability

Suppose i have a bag with all letters of the alfabet. I pick $1$ letter and i put it back. I pick like this 20 letters (so duplicates are allowed).

I need to calculate the change that i can form a certain word with this sequence, while at the same time NOT being able to form 3 other words.

Example:

SISTRAWIYLLYMNPLOBCT

What is the chance that i will be able to construct the word:

WILLYISSMART     (because all letters are present)

while at the same time NOT being able to construct:

KELLYISSMART    (because no K is present for example)

HUGOISSMART    (because no H is present for example)

IVANISSMART     (because only one A is present for example)

Answer (score 1):

You have $26$ latters $AB\dots Z$ and you want to construct the word: $WILLYISSMART$, so let's start with the first latter $W$ the probability to choose this latter is $\text{Pr}(W)=\frac{1}{26}$, but $W$ also should be appeard in $\psi:= SISTRAWIYLLYMNPLOBCT$ the probability for that is $\text{Pr}(W\in \psi)=\frac{1}{20}$ so since that the event are independent $\text{Pr}(W\cap W\in \psi)=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{26}\cdot \frac{1}{20}}$

For the second latter $I$ the probability choose $I$ is $\text{Pr}(I)=\frac{1}{26}$ but $I$ also should be appeard in $\psi:= SISTRAWIYLLYMNPLOBCT$ the probability for that is $\text{Pr}(I\in \psi)=\frac{1}{19}$
so since that the event are independent $\text{Pr}(I\cap I\in \psi)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{26}\cdot \frac{1}{19}}$. do the same for the rest.

The final answer will be $\color{blue}{\frac{1}{26}\cdot \frac{1}{20}}\cdot \color{red}{\frac{1}{26}\cdot \frac{1}{19}} \cdot \underbrace{\dots}_{\text{the rest}}$